# How to set datetimepicker options dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the options of [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) datetimepicker plugin, but I need it to be dynamically.

Here is this in my controller

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var today = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'days');

    $scope.datetimepickerOptions = {
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      defaultDate: today // here I need to set today or tomorrow
    };

 });
```

and here my html

```
// today option should be here
<input datetimepicker
       datetimepicker-options="{{datetimepickerOptions}}"/>

// tomorrow option should be here
<input datetimepicker
       datetimepicker-options="{{datetimepickerOptions}}"/>
```

that options are to set the initial values of the inputs/fields, in the first I need to set today's date so the user may see it, and in the second, it should be tomorro's date.

what do you recommend ?

**EDIT**

I did it like this

```
    $scope.datetimepickerOptions = {
      todayOptions: {
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        defaultDate: today
      },
      tomorrowOptions: {
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
        defaultDate: tomorrow
      }
    };
```

but I am getting this error

```
TypeError: option todayOptions is not recognized!
```

Comment: Why do you use document.ready event? Scope must be inside angular controller

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly it doesn't have nothing to do with my issue. I have that for another thing

Comment: Then you need to call scope.$apply after document.ready

Answer (score 0):

What about separating your options into two sets?

```
$scope.datetimepickerOptions1 = {
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      defaultDate: today
    };

$scope.datetimepickerOptions2 = {
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      defaultDate: tomorrow 
    };
```